# Strange NSObject to cocos2d random initialise

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsobject

I have a strange question. I'm creating an advent calendar as part of a Xmas update and am trying to prevent unlocking the same prize twice (the prizes are used elsewhere in the app).

The prize list is being stored in a plist as it seemed a quick way to input/read the data.

```
-(Prize*)getPrizeForDay:(NSInteger)integer
{
    NSString* plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"XmasPresents" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray* contentArray = (NSArray*)[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSDictionary* dictionary = (NSDictionary*)[contentArray objectAtIndex:integer-1];

Prize* prize = (Prize*)[Prize prizeWithType:[[dictionary objectForKey:@"ContentId"]intValue] andName:[dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"] andContent:[dictionary objectForKey:@"Content"] andAnswer:[dictionary objectForKey:@"Answer"]];

if(![self.calendarPrizes containsObject:prize])
[self.calendarPrizes addObject:prize];
else
    prize.unlocked = YES;

return prize;
```

}

self.calendarPrizes is being initialised in the app delegate on didFinishLaunching if it doesn't exist and stored in the NSUserDefaults when exiting. This function is within a singleton class.

The strangeness occurs when running the function again the NSArray is no longer an NSArray, the NSDictionary is no longer a dictionary and the Prize is no longer a prize!!! They are all initialised as random Cocos2d objects. Consequently the prize can be added multiple times.

Basically HELP!

UPDATE

This character only occurs in iOS6, having test on iOS 5 test device this morning it works as expected.

Comment: The saving code would be helpful. I'm guessing that's where the problem is.

Comment: It only saves when the application closes. If I run this function twice it behaves differently on both occasions.

Answer (score 0):

So I have discovered [NSArray containsObject:] won't work on custom objects. You either have to override isEqual method on NSObject or use a predicate (I chose the later).

```
 NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",prize.name];
NSArray* predicateArray = [self.calendarPrizes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if(predicateArray.count > 0)
{
    prize.unlocked = YES;
}
else
{
    [self.calendarPrizes addObject:prize];
}

return prize;
```

The strange behaviour still persists but it is no longer a problem so I'm moving on for now but it would be nice to know why these objects appear as the wrong class.